# How do I query for models with empty serialized fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, arel

When I have a model like,

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :shipping_lines

    ...
end
```

How can I find all records where `shipping_lines` is empty? If I do,

```
Order.select(order.shipping_lines).limit(5)
```

I get,

```
=> [#<Order id: nil, shipping_lines: [#<ShippingLine:0x007f8c5d10ced0>]>,
 #<Order id: nil, shipping_lines: [#<ShippingLine:0x007f8c6ef84718>]>,
 #<Order id: nil, shipping_lines: []>,
 #<Order id: nil, shipping_lines: []>,
 #<Order id: nil, shipping_lines: []>
```

But then the query `Order.where(shipping_lines: [])` yields `[]` and calling `to_sql` on the same query yields `=> "SELECT \"orders\".* FROM \"orders\"  WHERE 1=0"`

How should I go about selecting just the orders that have the default value, or an empty array, for their shipping lines?

Comment: Of course I have also tried `where(shipping_lines: nil)`, but this is always empty.

Answer (score 7):

The only way I found while working on similar issue in my project is to directly cast empty array to YAML like this:

```
Order.where(shipping_lines: [].to_yaml)
```

Looks like a dirty hack but at least it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that @raeno, it was driving me crazy.

Comment: For empty serialized hashes, I had to use something like:

`Order.where.not("shipping_lines = ?", {}.to_yaml)`